# Using output from dir to copy new files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to copy new files having the extension `.rdl` but whose name does not include `- Backup.rdl`.

I can get the list using `dir *.rdl /b | findstr /vi " - Backup.rdl"` but how do I use this list to copy new files?

Comment: pass *.rdl to robocopy with an  exclusion /xf backup.rdl - its included with 2k8; http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: It might also help to explain what "new" means

Answer (score 0):

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Source C:\Dest *.rdl /XF "* - Backup.rdl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to copy them into the copies directory, for example.  Notice the `^` in front of the `|`

```
for /f %i in ('dir *.rdl /b ^| findstr /vi " - Backup.rdl"') do copy %i copies
```

If you want it in a batch file you need `%%i`

```
for /f %%i in ('dir *.rdl /b ^| findstr /vi " - Backup.rdl"') do copy %%i copies
```